Bootstrap table collapse rows if data row is greater than 1
I'm doing a python Flask app that takes user input data and display them on bootstrap + html page. I'm doing perfectly fine if I want to display all input data row by row. However, I thought I'd be great to have a collapse (accordian) row if the data is under the same category.
Following is an example of the data format (python dictionary) passing.
## all products are based on apple ## 

fruit = [{"name": ["apple", "red apple", "green apple", "yellow apple"], 
    "taste": ["crunchy", "juicy", "sweet", "sour"], 
    "price": [5, 4, 4, 2]}]


## single product ##

fruit = [{"name": ["watermelon"], "taste": ["sweet"], "price": [4.5]}]

On Flask app
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", data = fruit)

Html (doing okay for single product)
<tbody>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row["name"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row["taste"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row["price"] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

This is what I tried to attempt for multiple input ...
<tbody>
    {% for row in data %}
        {% if row["name"]|length > 1 %}
            <tr>
                {% for item in row["name"] %}
                    <td>{{ item }}</td>
                {% endfor %}

                {% for item in row["taste"] %}
                    <td>{{ item }}</td>
                {% endfor %}

                {% for item in row["price"] %}
                    <td>{{ item }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

This is what I am expecting ...
collapse/expand table
I found above table from https://codepen.io/n3k1t/pen/OJMGgyq.
I think my problem is on how my data input is structured. I cannot think of the other ways to work this out. Help!
